# Understanding mysql charset and collation

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, innodb, collation

I have an `InnoDB` table in mysql with `utf8` charset and `utf8_general_ci` collation.
After the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `ticket`
WHERE `text` LIKE '%abc%'
ORDER BY `created_date` DESC
```

it returns me the rows containing "äbc" as well as containing "abc". I've tried to use `utf8_bin` collation on table, but it didn't helped.

What I've missed?

P.S. I thought that the problem is in the PHP connection charset, but after executing the query on Sequel Pro, I've got the same result.

Comment: Note that you probably need to change the collation on the *field*, not the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for the unicode collation (both utf8_general_ci and utf8_unicode_ci) you have this kind of equalities:

```
Ä = A
Ö = O
Ü = U
```

this is not a bug.

read this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-unicode-sets.html and this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collation-effect.html